# Custom xml de/serialization in ConfigurationSection (like using IConfigurationSectionHandler)

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, xml-serialization

I would like to use my own custom XML format in my Web.config. In .Net 1.1 I was using IConfigurationSectionHandler combined with XmlSerializer. Because IConfigurationSectionHandler is depreciated, I want to do the same with ConfigurationSection. I tried it like this:

```
    protected override void DeserializeSection(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        // my custom code to deserialize data from reader
    }
```

If I start my application, I get a Parser Error saying: "Unrecognized configuration section mySection/customChildNode". This happens before DeserializeSection is called. What am I doing wrong? Any hint how to use custom xml in a ConfigurationSection?

**Edit: a bit mor code as requested**

I tried to implement my section like this:

```
public class MySection : ConfigurationSection
{
    protected override void DeserializeSection(XmlReader reader)
    {
        // my code
    }
}
```

and register it in the Web.config like this:

```
<sectionGroup name="mySection" type="myNamspace.MySection, myAssembly"/>
```

then I try to use it like this:

```
<mySection>
  <abc><xx/></abc>
</mySection>
```

I would assume that the DeserializeSection of my ConfigurationSection is called and the passed in XmlReader allows access to the contained custom XML. But DeserializeSection is not called and a get an error saying that mySection/abc is unknown.

Comment: You're going to have to show a bit more code than that. Please post enough code for us to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `<section>` instead of `<sectionGroup>`.